# Windows Server 2016 how to unlock DLL

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, dll

I've a Windows Server 2016 installation with Exchange 2016.

I need to unblock a downloaded DLL as asked into this [guide](https://www.tuescher.net/Exchange-Sender-Based-Routing/e16.html).

In Windows Server 2012, you need to right-click and then click to UNBLOCK.
In 2016 there is no block button.

How can I unblock a DLL? Do I still need to unblock it?
I'am a Domain Admin, do I need some special priviledges or group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a file does not have an `Unblock` checkbox on its properties dialog, it means there is nothing to unblock and you don't have to do anything.

To find out whether you need to unblock a file, you can look for a secondary data stream, in PowerShell:

```
Get-Item \pathto\exchange.dll -stream *
```

If you see an entry:

```
Stream        : Zone.Identifier
```

it usually means you should unblock the file because it was downloaded from the internet, you can use PowerShell again:

```
Unblock-File \pathto\exchange.dll
```

If the DLL came in a zip file and you already unblocked the zip file before extracting the DLL, you don't have to unblock the DLL itself.